# How to get data from html page using java?

Tags: java, android, html, xml, xml-parsing

How to get data from XML/HTML page?

I'd like to make an android app, in which users get a notification of a school-lesson that fell out. 
This is what the website looks like: 
http://www.anony.ws/image/pC9

Users fill in their school class (klas) after the installation of the app.
I want to pick the data from the table, users should receive a notification if it's their class. (example:

```
if ( userClass == klas ), then alert ("hey, " + was + " will be " + was + "because of" + opmerking);
```

something like that. But I have no idea how I should pick the data out of the table, it's a weird page. Makes it even more difficult because the page fades from (1/2) to (2/2) (max 10 listings each page, so 50 listings = 5 pages) , find out example here: http://suse.ghlyceum.nl/dagrooster/lwoo/. 
How I should pick the data and put them in java vars!

Example from code I need to pick things out

```
<tr class='list odd'>
<td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
<td class="list" align="center">5</td>
<td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
<td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
<td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
<td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
<td class="list" align="center">D03</td>
<td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>
```

Full website code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Roosterwijzigingen Locatie Rijnwoude</title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<style type="text/css">
<!--

/* page title */
div.mon_title 
{   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;  
}

table.info
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
}

table.mon_list
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
}

td.info
{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
 }

th.list,
td.list
{
    background-color: #FFB515;
    font-size: 19pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:solid;
 }

-->
</style>
<meta name="generator" content="Untis 2013">
<meta name="company" content="Gruber &amp; Petters Software, A-2000 Stockerau, Austria, www.grupet.at">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FEE9B1">
<CENTER>
<TABLE  align="bottom" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">
<TR>
<TD align="bottom">
<font face="Verdana" size="6" color="#911083">Roosterwijzigingen</font>
<br><font size="4" color="#000000" face="Arial">Vestiging Rijnwoude</font>
</TD>

<TD>&nbsp;</TD>

<TD>

<TABLE width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD></TD>
  <TD>   </TD>
  <TD><font size="-2">Gewijzigd 16-5-2013 13:54</size></TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>

</TD>

</tr>
</TABLE>
<p>

<font size="4" face="Arial">
<div class="mon_title">18-05-2013 Maandag</div>
<table class="mon_list" >
    <tr class='list'>
        <th class="list" align="center">Klas</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">uur</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">was</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">wordt</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">was</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">wordt</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">Vaklokaal</th>
        <th class="list" align="center">opmerking</th>
    </tr>



<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">4H</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">5-6</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">nat1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">MEn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">aulauur</td>
</tr>

<tr class='list even'>
    <td class="list" align="center">4V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">econ3</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">econ3</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">SVn</td></td>
    <td class="list" align="center">SVn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">310</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>

</tr>

<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">5</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">fatl1</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MPs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">D03</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">lokaal wissel</td>

</tr>

<tr class='list even'>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">8</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">gs</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">NBa</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">---</td>
    <td class="list" align="center" style="background-color: #6f95d5">aulauur</td>
</tr>

<tr class='list odd'>
    <td class="list" align="center">6V</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">nat7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">nat7</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">MEn</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">JHo</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">001</td>
    <td class="list" align="center">het 6e of 8e uur</td>
</tr>


</table>
<p>
<font size="3" face="Arial">
Groene Hart Rijnwoude
</font></font>

</CENTER>
<p><center><font face="Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.grupet.at" target="_blank" >Untis roostersoftware</a></font></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use javascript to get the broad data. In your case Table with class 'mon_list'. Then you can use xml parsing to get specific data and store them in java variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML parsers only on well-formed HTML documents. For parsing HTML document such as the one you have posted (which does not seem to be well-formed), use of [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is recommended. Read the cookbook introduction and you should be good to go in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The page output is in HTML. So, my preference will be to use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/). Its standard, easy and cuts through every piece of HTML you give it.

In your android project include the JSOUP libraries. They are relatively moderate in size and worth the effort because your application seems as if it is going to read a lot of html.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Get The Site and Parse it
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://suse.ghlyceum.nl/dagrooster/lwoo/").get();
    // Select Table
    Element table = document.select(".mon_list").first();

    Iterator<Element> lines = table.select("tr").iterator();
    while (lines.hasNext()) {
        Element line = lines.next();
        System.out.println("TD text : "+line.text());
    }
}
```

This is just the java code. So, you can use this in conjunction with the existing Android Code to populate a list element (rather than output onto console as shown in code) and show that in the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
         URL url = new URL("http://facebook.com");
         in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
         String inputLine;
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
           {
             System.out.println(inputLine);
           }
```

Should be enough to get you started .